# virt-manager in php

Tags: virtualization, php, kvm-virtualization

can anybody help me to display details about the VM using PHP code. am using Ubuntu server and used KVM as hypervisor. Am trying to display cores, ram, memory alloted each VM.

i have tried all the shell commands in php using shell_exec and exec.

Without installing any tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can install libvirt php extension to communicate wit libvirtd. See the instructions here.

http://libvirt.org/compiling.html

Once installed you can tryout some sample examples like :

```
<?php
 print_r( libvirt_version() );
?>
```

Sample Output of above code will be something like:

```
Array
(
    [libvirt.release] => 0
    [libvirt.minor] => 0
    [libvirt.major] => 1
    [connector.version] => 0.4.5
    [connector.major] => 0
    [connector.minor] => 4
    [connector.release] => 5
)
php
```

Refer http://libvirt.org/php/examples.html for more examples.

The complete API reference can be found here: http://libvirt.org/php/api-reference.html

Hope this helps

Comment: is it possible to have php code alone to get the output. i dont want any tool to be installed

Comment: Its not a tool its a PHP extension.